# Issue recognising Abs[w]*Sign[w]=w equality

Tags: simplifying-expressions

Mathematica was unable to validate the first identity here, even though I believe it is correct, and even though it is able to validate the second one.

```
In[158]:= Abs[w] == w Sign[w] // FullSimplify

Out[158]= Abs[w] == w Sign[w]

In[159]:= Abs[w] Sign[w] == w // FullSimplify

Out[159]= True
```

Could someone please explain why this behaviour is occurring, and how to rectify it?

Comment: Mathematica is correct, your believe is not. `Sign[w]!=1/Sign[w]` for complex `w`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Since both `Abs` and `Sign` are  complex function. `Abs[w]` define by `Sqrt[w*Conjugate[w]]` and `Sign[w]` define by `w/Abs[w]` for complex number `w`.

```
FullSimplify[Abs[w] == w Sign[w], w ∈ Reals]
```

> `True`.

- To compare with `Sign`, We can also use `RealAbs` since now `w` is real.

```
RealAbs[w] == w Sign[w] // FullSimplify
```

- According to the definition `Sign[w]=w/Abs[w]`, that is why

```
Abs[w] Sign[w] == w // FullSimplify
(* True *)
```

Comment: (+1) and perhaps a noteworthy comment: `Reduce[Abs[w] == w Sign[w], w, Reals]` also yields `True`